# How can I do division of these fields and aggregate

Tags: django

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class WorkDone(models.Model):
    worker = models.ManyToManyField(Worker, related_name='workers')
    work_title = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True, null=True)
    units = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.work_title)
```

views

```
  context['work_done_by_single_person'] = Worker.objects.all() \
            .values('name', 'workers__work_title')\
            .order_by('name') \
            .annotate(total_work=(
        Sum('workers__units')/Count('name'))
        )
  print(context['workers'])
```

print output

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'dinesh', 'workers__work_title': 'first', 'total_work': 4}, {'name': 'ramesh', 'workers__work_title': 'first', 'total_work': 4}]>
```

instead of 4 it should be 2 as the total unit is 4 and no. of worker is 2

Comment: I think the problem is that you are summing up the workers unit, so it becomes like `(4 + 4) / 2` rather than simply doing `4 / 2`

Comment: what I am looking for is work done by single person, if there are three people for a job instance, it should divide the unit by 3

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you're unable to do this as you can't perform arithmetic on aggregates. You would have to do get a count in a separate aggregate variable and then in your annotate, do the math there.

For now, Django does not allow SubQueries to be performed in an annotate.

```
total_worker__units = Worker.objects.values('workers__work_title').count()
context['workers'] = Worker.objects.all() \
            .values('name', 'workers__work_title')\
            .order_by('name') \
            .annotate(total_work=(
        total/Count('name'))
        )
```

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28296 for details

Comment: your suggestion works only for a single instance, if there is multiple instance, the output is wrong